# simple html dom only extract empty class

Tags: php, parsing, css-selectors, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the data that sits in the label element with an empty class, or a class that isn't disabled. Unfortunately none of the selectors I've tried, like the jQuery ":Not" selector are working.

The code I have this far is:

```
$element = $html->find('div .titleHeader label', 0);
```

Which ideally would extract:
110 out of:

```
<label for="attribute76">
<input id="attribute76" class="jshide" type="radio" value="76" name="super_attribute[144]">
110
</label>
```

and not 105 out of:

```
<label class="disabled" for="attribute75">
<span class="crossedStock"> </span>
<input id="attribute75" class="jshide" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="75" name="super_attribute[144]">
105
</label>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. `label[class='disabled']` does give me a return, but for example: `label[class!='disabled']` doesn't work either.

Comment: There is no div there, so obviously there's no chance of this working.

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = $('div .titleHeader label')find('input', 0);

alert(element);
```

You can do this with the help of jquery

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Unless I did something wrong:
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('URL');

$element = $html->find('h1', 0);
echo $element->plaintext."<br>\n";


$element = $html->find('.price', 0);
echo $element->plaintext."<br>\n";


$element = $html->find('div .titleHeader label[class=""]', 0);
echo $element->plaintext."<br>\n";


?>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
var element = $('div .titleHeader label')find('input', 0);

alert(element);
</script>`

Comment: Annoyingly, it works with
`$element = $html->find('div .titleHeader label[for!=attribute72]', 0);`
but not with the class attribute, which is what I need.
`$element = $html->find('div .titleHeader label[class!=disabled]', 0);`
Any ideas?